# Does counter cache respect counter_sql or conditions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, counter-cache

In Rails 3.2, is association option `counter_cache` linked to other options such as `counter_sql` or `conditions`?

For example, if I have an association like this:

```
class User
  has_many :items, :through => :orders
  has_many :active_items, :through => :orders
           :conditions => 'active = true', :source => :item

class Order
  belongs_to :users, :counter_cache => :active_items_count
  belongs_to :items

class Item
  has_many :users, :through => :orders
```

Will the counter cache respect that *active* condition? (meaning inactive items won't be counted)
And what about using `finder_sql`/`counter_sql`

Answer (score 0):

I end up rarely using counter cache for the reasons you mention, and instead, always create my own.  React to on_save and on_create callbacks and call a method to update the count.

One tip if you do create you're own, use `@instance.update_column(:column, value)`.  This will make sure callbacks aren't called recursively.